# Group button in res.partner not working in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a group selection button and is_group boolean field to inherited res.partner model but when added the group button the function compute_company_type not working
My code is

```
class Partner(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

company_type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('group', 'Group')])
refered = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string="Refered By")
import1 = fields.Float(string="Import")
temp_import = fields.Float(string="Temporary Import")
export = fields.Float(string="Export")
temp_export = fields.Float(string="Temporary Export")
transit = fields.Float(string="Transit")
group_id = fields.Many2one('res.group', string='Related Group', index=True)
is_group = fields.Boolean(string='Is a group', default=False)
is_company = fields.Boolean(string='Is a company', default=False)

@api.depends('is_company', 'is_group')
def _compute_company_type(self):
    for partner in self:
        if partner.is_group:
            partner.company_type = 'group'
        elif partner.is_company:
            partner.company_type = 'company'
        else:
            partner.company_type = 'person'

def _write_company_type(self):
    for partner1 in self:
        if partner1.company_type == 'group':
            partner1.is_group = partner1.company_type
        elif partner1.company_type == 'company':
            partner1.is_company = partner1.company_type
        else:
            partner1.company_type = 'person'   

@api.onchange('company_type')
def onchange_company_type(self):
    for partner in self:
        if partner.company_type == 'group':
            partner.is_group = (partner.company_type == 'group')
        elif partner.company_type == 'company':
            partner.is_company = (partner.company_type == 'company')
        else:
            partner.company_type = 'person'
```

I need one more company type button ie group if group button is TRUE need to change fields accordingly in res.partner form

Comment: Is `_compute_company_type` a button function?

Comment: @TerrencePoe _compute_company_type is a compute function in res.partner.py to determine company_type

Comment: May I know what issue you are getting after adding new option "group" in selection of company_type?

Comment: @MitalVaghani I cannot select group option in res partner form

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: sometimes when i click group button its getting true value. but i cannot change company_type to individual or company  after that

Answer (score -1):

If you want to rewrite  _compute_company_type function from res.partner you must inherit your custom model from res.partner, something like this:

```
from odoo.addons.base.res import res_partner as res_partner


class CRMLeadPropertyMulti(res_partner.Partner):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    ## Your Code ##
    @api.depends('is_company', 'is_group')
    def _compute_company_type(self):
        for partner in self:
            partner.company_type = 'company' if partner.is_company else 'group' if partner.is_group else 'person'

    @api.onchange('company_type')
    def onchange_company_type(self):
        self.is_company = (self.company_type == 'company')
        self.is_group = (self.company_type == 'group')
```

I think it could be a good idea to make false or true each case evaluating as bool if is a group or a company, that way if one is true the other is false, this can guard the consistency.

Answer (score -3):

Your field `is_group` is a boolean. I don't know what you meant by this `if partner.is_group:`.

Boolean field is have only two values and they are true or false. Without checking true or false you won't get any result.

Try with the true or false and let me know.

Comment: Python is checking whether the condition is true in the if statement. So he don't need to specifically mention it in case of boolean fields.

Comment: As @MihranThalhath said we don't need specifically mention true or false.